# How do you register a new token symbol?

Tags: ether

We are creating a new ERC223 token and can't find clear info on who controls the token symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody regulates or governs the use of symbols.

You can use any symbol you like, even if it's been used before. It might be prudent to choose one that hasn't been used before, though there's no way to stop somebody then cloning your contract, including its symbol, and deploying to the network.

Comment: Then I would think a federal trademark law would supersede any duplicate activity? Meaning if we have a federal trademark for AAA, then no one else could legally use it for the same function? Just like a domain name, you can register whatever you wish, but if you register www.applephone.com you are in a bit a trouble.

Comment: That would depend on where you are in the world. A "symbol squatter" in a warehouse in China couldn't care less about US law :-) Furthermore, if I create a contract containing your symbol, and I don't build that contract in a way that allows it to be removed in future (i.e. no `selfdestruct()`), then even if you prosecuted me under your country's laws, there's no way I could remove that contract (and therefore duplicate symbol) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official registry for token symbols. There can be multiple tokens with the same symbol. The distinction comes from the contract address.

There was a discussion about creating an official registry in this [EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/740). AFAIK, there are no plans to create one.