# How "polymath" is doing "Ticker symbol reservation" on Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, dapp-development, decentralized-exchange

So, from what I understand it is not possible to reserve the ticker symbol on the Ethereum network (I read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44241/how-do-you-register-a-new-token-symbol/44242) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41419/how-do-companies-register-ico-ticker)) But I am trying to understand what the Polymath is doing by "Ticker symbol reservation" and asking for 1000 POLY for doing that. I saw this sentence written on their token studio page [here](https://eth-tokenstudio.polymath.network/). You can also see the screenshot of the page below (just in case). Can someone explain to me what are they reserving and where are they reserving?

[image: polymath ticker reservation]

Comment: They sell a service for creating security tokens. Reserve symbol probably means to reserve within their platform.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael When you say "platform" you don't mean the Ethereum mainnet right? You mean "in their company, the Polymath" (or something like that).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Anyone can use any name they want for a token in Ethereum, so it is not possible to reserve them.